Why do ADC interleaving DC offset spurs alias into the first Nyquist zone after a decimation filter?
In the TI application note Spurs Analysis in the RF Sampling ADC, DC offset errors in time-interleaved ADCs are said to produce spurs at $k f_s / M$, where $k$ is an integer, $f_s$ is the overall sample rate and $M$ is the number of interleaved ADCs. The document later states

The RF ADC integrates digital downconverters (DDC) to shift the spectrum in the RF frequency to baseband. The DDC also shifts the spurs. The main functional block of the DDC is the NCO and decimation filter. The NCO shifts the desired frequency and all of the spurs. Then, the data passes through the decimation filter which consists of a decimator and digital low-pass filter. The processing of the decimation filter is equivalent to changing the sampling rate to Fs/m, and passing the data through an analog anti-aliasing filter at fc = Fs/2m, where m = decimation count. As a result, the spurs alias to the first Nyquist zone which ranges from [-Fs/2m, Fs/2m] (complex output), by shifting the frequency of k × Fs/m (k = 0, 1, 2,…).

I don't understand this. The decimation filter should act as a filter with passband $[-f_s/2m, +f_s/2m)$, followed by a downsampling block by $m$. Now, if this were a perfect brick wall filter, any spurs outside $[-f_s/2m, +f_s/2m)$ should be completely removed, not alias, right? Of course, the filter is not a brick wall filter so these spurs would be greatly attenuated, and then alias, but this seems to indicate they alias unattenuated.
I've measured DC offset spurs on real RF-ADCs and these spurs do indeed alias into the final, decimated first Nyquist zone, so this analysis has to be correct in some sense, but I don't understand it.
For example, we can take the case of an RF-ADC sampling at 2.5 GSPS using 4 interleaving ADCs, an NCO frequency of -1531.25 MHz, and decimation of 40.
I would calculate the location of the spurs using something like the following simple Python script:
import numpy as np

def falias(f, fs):
    ret = f % fs
    if ret >= fs / 2:
        ret -= fs
    return ret

fs = 2500
fnco = -1531.25
M = 4
m = 40
f = np.array([falias(i, fs) for i in fs * np.arange(-M // 2, M // 2) / M + fnco])
print(sorted(f))
print([falias(i, fs / 40) for i in f])

This prints out
[-906.25, -281.25, 343.75, 968.75]
[-31.25, -31.25, -31.25, -31.25]

The first printed line is where I expect the spurs to be after the NCO but before decimation filtering. As I stated above, I would then expect the decimation filter to greatly attenuate everything outside $[-31.25, +31.25)$. But, a real measurement shows the spur at -31.25. This spur is also strong enough that I don't think it's explained by it being greatly attenuated and then aliased.
